# PHP - How do i display the first 20 li then have a link to display more (gallery)

Tags: php, list

I want to display about 20 li on a page with a link at the bottom that says something like 'display more'. This link will then clear the first 20 and display the next 20. How should i go about doing this. (I am creating a gallery)

I was thinking about using PHP and MySQL. However for what I am doing I do not really need to store it in a database so is there an easier way of doing it only using html, php or javascript?

thanks

Comment: So then how *are* you going to store it?

Comment: Keyword: ["pagination"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+pagination). This is a *well-discussed* topic (e.g. try some interweb searches) and thus I am voting to close. (Try some things, and *then*, if there are *specific problems*, formulate a focused SO question...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 $list_images=glob('imagesPath'.'*.{jpg|jpeg|png|gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

 if(isset($_REQUEST['page_id']))
 {
     $pageNo=$_REQUEST['page_id'];
 }    
 if($pageNo =='') 
     $offset=0;
 else
      $offset=$pageNo; 

 for($i=$offset; $i<($offset+20); $i++)
 {
      echo"<a href=''><img src='$list_images[$i]' /> </a>";
 }
```

// Store the page no in a hidden variable

```
 <input type='submit' value='More' onclick ='pageSet()' />
```

//Javascript

```
   function pageSet()
   { 
    var id=document.getElementById('page_id').value;

     if(id =='')
     { 
          document.getElementById('page_id').value =1;
     }
     else
     {
            document.getElementById('page_id').value =parseInt(id)+1;
     }   

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As some people said in their comments the subject is too general. But here is the general answer.

You can do this with javascript. You can create a javascript array that contains **all** the records that you need to display in your list. If the 'display more' button is clicked you can trigger a javascript function that clears the page and writes another set of items from your list. You just have to maintain the pointers to beginning and end of the current list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the plugin that you can use.

http://www.geckonewmedia.com/blog/2009/8/20/simplepager---jquery-paging-plugin--updated

But let me know if you need any custom code

Comment: I want this but instead of having two different lists one for the content and one for the previous,next and pages. i want to get rid of the page numbers and just have something like this 

1. page 1 
2. page 2
3. page 3
4. page 4
5. next

then on when it click on the next page it will go like this

6. previous
7. page 5
8. page 6
9. page 7
10. next

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution, doing what you describe, without any javascript and DB, just store your files to disk:

```
<?php
$array = file('file.txt');
$from   = isset($_GET['from'])?$_GET['from']:0;
echo '<pre>';
for($i=($from+0);$i<($from+20) && $i<count($array);$i++) {
    echo '#'.$i.' '.$array[$i];
}
echo '</pre><a href="?from='.($from+20).'">MORE</a><br />';
```